# Can we sort test errors in mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Assume I have a test file as follows:

```js
describe('my tests', function() {
  it('t1 ...', cb);
  it('t2 ...', cb);
  it('t3 ...', cb);
  it('t4 ...', cb);
  // ...
})
```

Suppose I got errors in t2 and t3. My goal is to fix the error tests serially one after the other. So I have to fix t2 and then t3, and, so on.

But in the mocha report, the errors are sorted serially as how they occur in the test file. So t2 error is reported before t3, and, so on.

The problem is if there are many tests (10+) (it gets worse with very long stacktraces) I'd have to scroll a lot to find the first error (t2). I am looking at some command line switch which will report t2 to the end, and, all the later errors to the top.

Comment: I'm curious: why not fixing the test cases in the opposite order they are reported? So if t4, t2, and t1 fail, you would first fix t4, then t2 and t1 as the last one?

Comment: No. I'd do it the opposite way. Fix t1, t2, and, at the last, t4. Because that is the way we author the tests. Perhaps t2 inserts data. In t4 we validate the count of records...

Comment: Er... Shouldn't test cases be independent of each other? The order in which they are executed shouldn't matter. If one test depends on another, then there's a problem in the design of the tests and not the reporting.

Comment: And the reason for that is that if some test case depends on another, then if the first one fails, the second one will also fail no matter if the logic it covers is correct or not. And such a result incorrectly tells you that a code covered by t2 and t4 is wrong while in fact, only the test t2 is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it this is what you are looking for but you could try running mocha with the `bail` option. This will cause mocha to exit at the first test failure so that you only have to deal with one error at a time.

Comment: Correct. The sad part however is, I already have used this before ‍♂️a long while back...Thankyou.